# Why does a single module import add 1.5 seconds to a pytest run?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest

I am writing some code with TDD and have a test that looks like this (note I am using [pytest-describe](https://github.com/ropez/pytest-describe), but the same issue exists when using my tests without the additional formatting):

```py
import numpy as np
import pytest
from maszcal.emulator import LensingEmulator, LargeErrorWarning




class FakeInterpolator:
    def __init__(self, coords, grid):
        pass

    def process(self):
        pass

    def interp(self, coords):
        return np.ones(tuple(c.size for c in coords))


def describe_emulator():

    def describe_error_check():

        @pytest.fixture
        def emulator(mocker):
            mocker.patch('maszcal.emulator.RbfInterpolator', new=FakeInterpolator)
            lensing_emulator = LensingEmulator()
            lensing_emulator.generate_grid = lambda coords: np.ones(tuple(c.size for c in coords))
            return lensing_emulator

        def other_test_1(emulator):
            do_stuff_with_emulator...
```

This test takes 2.5-3 seconds to run even with `pytest --collectonly`. When `LensingEmulator` gets imported, it imports from the `maszcal.interpolate` module like so:

```
spec/emulator/LensingEmulator.py
    imports ↑  
maszcal/emulator.py
    imports ↑
maszcal/interpolate.py
    imports ↑
          GPy
```

where [GPy](https://gpy.readthedocs.io/en/deploy/) is an external module. Of course there are other dependencies, but what is odd is that if I delete the `import GPy` line from `maszcal.interpolate` I get a speedup to 0.9ish seconds instead of 2.5-3.

I am fairly confused by this behavior because importing the module by itself is not that slow, but it adds a ridiculous amount of time the collection phase of the test. What is the proper way to address this issue?

Comment: It could be not only that importing the module is slow, but also that whatever processing `mazcal/interpolate` does with that as soon as it's imported is *also* slow.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy That module only contains imports and class definitions, so I don't think so.